# Hide task bar in maximized state when WindowStyle is SingleBorderWindow

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm putting an option in my settings window for my user to choose whether to show the Windows Task Bar or to completely go FullScreen when he Maximize the Window.

I tried this

```
static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
    const uint SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    const uint SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    const uint SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;

    public static void SetFormTopMost()
    {
        IntPtr windowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle;
        SetWindowPos(windowHandle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                     SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    }
```

But this is not working. Not even making it the TopMost..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method:

```
    public void MaximizeWindow(bool IsFullScreenWithTaskbar)
    {
        if (IsFullScreenWithTaskbar)
        {
            this.MaxHeight = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;             
        }
        this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
        this.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
        this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    }
```

Comment: It is making the user not able to resize anymore. Thats not what i wanted. What i want was that i'm gona keep a check box in my Settings window named **Allow Full Screen**. When he checks that and when he clicks the maximise button, the window should go completely Full hiding the task bar.

Comment: You can easily remove the Resize Mode :) and you can use instead of "this" your window : Application.Current.MainWindow. Was just an example. No problem for downvoting, it happens :)

Comment: No. i'm not the one who downvoted. I got a new information that a complete full screen can be achieved when the ResizeMode is set to NoResize. Also i won't be able to change the resize mode. Just think, if i go fullScreen using this code, the restore button will be disabled, not letting me to go back to Normal size. Even StateChanged event won't trigger until i try to minimize, then where should i place the code to remove ResizeMode?

Comment: This code will not work as needed, first of all `MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight` never returns your monitor size but rather, as written over at msdn `the height, in pixels, of a maximized top-level window on the primary display monitor.`. Another thing is that having a window the height of the monitor only hides the taskbar, which is still rendered.

Comment: For Sayka: when you care in full screen mode, you can go back to normal size by double-clicking the window (top bar) and you can reset ResizeMode on SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged.

Comment: DisplaySettingsChanged is not fired (as i said before, sorry), but SizeChanged yes. you can reset ResizeMode on this event

Comment: Yes. Even the StateChanged Event is also getting fired. But for that, the user has to Double Click the window. Cauz the restore and minimize button are gone when ResizeMode is set to NoResize.